# Python: command line, sys.argv, "if __name__ == '__main__' "

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, argv

I have a moderate amount of experience using Python in Jupyter but am pretty clueless about how to use the command line. I have this prompt for a homework assignment -- I understand how the algorithms work, but I don't know how to format everything so it works from the command line in the way that is specified.

The prompt:

> Question 1: 80 points
>
> Input: a text file that specifies a travel problem (see travel-input.txt
> for the format) and a search algorithm
> (more details are below).
>
> `python map.py [file] [search]` should read
> the travel problem from “file” and run the “search” algorithm to find
> a solution. It will print the solution and its cost.
>
> search is one of
> [DFTS, DFGS, BFTS, BFGS, UCTS, UCGS, GBFTS, GBFGS, ASTS, ASGS]

Here is the template I was given:

```
from search import ... # TODO import the necessary classes and methods
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    input_file = sys.argv[1]
    search_algo_str = sys.argv[2]
    
    # TODO implement
    
    goal_node = ... # TODO call the appropriate search function with appropriate parameters
    
    # Do not change the code below.
    if goal_node is not None:
        print("Solution path", goal_node.solution())
        print("Solution cost", goal_node.path_cost)
    else:
        print("No solution was found.")
```

So as far as `python map.py [file] [search]` goes, 'file' refers to `travel-input.txt` and 'search' refers to one of `DFTS, DFGS, BFTS,`... etc - a user-specified choice. My questions:

1. Where do I put my search functions? Should they all just be back-to-back in the same block of code?
2. How do I get the command line to recognize each function from its four or five-letter code? Is it just the name of the function? If I call it just using those letters, how can the functions receive input?
3. Do I need to reference the input file anywhere in my code?
4. Does it matter where I save my files in order for them to be accessible from the command line - .py files, travel-input.txt, etc? I've tried accessing them from the command line, with no success.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function definitions go before the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block. To select the correct function you can put them in a dict and use the four-letter abbreviations as keys, i.e.

```
def dfts_search(...):
    ...

def dfgs_search(...):
    ....

...

if __name__ == "__main__":

    input_file = sys.argv[1]
    search_algo_str = sys.argv[2]
    
    search_dict = {"DFTS": dfts_search, "DFGS": dfgs_search, ...}

    try:
        func = search_dict[search_algo_str]
        result = func(...)
    except KeyError:
        print(f'{search_algo_str} is an unknown search algorithm')
```

Not sure what you mean by reference, but `input_file` already refers to the input file. You will need to write a function to read the file and process the contents.

The location of the files shouldn't matter too much. Putting everything in the same directory is probably easiest. In the command window, just cd to the directory where the files are located and run the script as described in the assignment.